# Migrating data to backup table (with foreign keys)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

The scenario (simplified):

Primary table:

```
id (pk)
description
date
```

Secondary table:

```
id (pk)
primaryid(fk)
description
```

Second table #2:

```
id (pk)
primaryid(fk)
description
```

Second table #3:

```
id (pk)
primaryid(fk)
description
```

Now I created backup table for each original table (script out - create). I want to move all data (including related data) with `date < 2014` in the primary table to backup tables and keep only newer records in primary table with one query (or as few as possible).

Whats the easiest and safest way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean copy data to all of the backup tables and also remove data from primary table?

Comment: yes. that is what i want

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to move the data with single query. Create a temp table and copy the Primary Table IDs based on your condition (like `date < 2014`) then copy the data from main tables to back-up tables joining with Temp table.

After that delete from your Primary tables using the ids from the temp table. Pseudo code for this.

```
Create Table #TempTable(Id primaryTableId)

insert into #TempTable
select Id from primaryTable where date < 2014

insert into Primary-backuptable(col1, col2,.. )
select col1, col2.. from primaryTable PT 
JOIN #TempTable TT ON PT.ID = TT.ID

--Copy related tables
--------
--------
DELETE related tables

DELETE FROM SECONDARYTABLE3 ST 
JOIN  primaryTable PT ON ST.PTId = PT.Id
JOIN #TempTable TT ON PT.ID = TT.ID
------
```